# How to get mAP in Tensorboard

Tags: dictionary, tensorflow, tensorboard

I trained several times and now have a lot of events.out.tfevents- files.
Now I would like to analyze these data in tensorboard because I need the accuracy/mAP of the different training sessions.
Problem now if I open tensorboard with my last training session:
tensorboard --logdir="./traing"
I only see learning rate and a Loss. (see printscreen)
How can i see more? Especially the accuracy/mAP?

I have `tensorflow/board 1.13.1` & `Ubuntu 18.04` and followed this [tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html).

[image: Screenshot Tensorboard]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create the evaluation data. For that run the below command.

```
python3 legacy/eval.py \
--logtostderr \
--pipeline_config_path=[path to config file] \
--checkpoint_dir=[path to checkpoints directory] \
--eval_dir=[path to directory to save evaluation data]
```

Note that this is done in tensorflow 1.3.1. The eval.py file may not be inside lagacy folder in your case.

For example see my command below.

```
python3 legacy/eval.py \
--logtostderr \
--pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config \
--checkpoint_dir=training/ \
--eval_dir=eval/
```

Then run tensorboard using the below command.

```
tensorboard --logdir=eval/
```

Here *eval* is the directory that you gave to save evaluation data.

Comment: Thanks. But this would show the mAP of evaluation dataset. How to check mAP of training dataset? This will be useful to check whether we have overfitted our model on training dataset.

Comment: I am pointing to the training data-set. So the evaluation is done on the training data-set.